# Redefining latex macro using same name

Tags: latex, macros, definition

Currently I use a `\mytodo macro`, which just calls `\todo[inline]`:

```
\newcommand{\pbtodo}[1]{\todo[inline]{#1}}
```

But I'd like to call this macro `\todo`. The simplest solution:

```
\renewcommand{\todo}[1][]{\todo{#1}}
```

unsurprisingly resulted in what I presume to be a stack overflow:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
```

Does anyone know a way to use the old `\todo` macro in a redefinition?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is answered elsewhere: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47351/2148

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I often [see advice on the web](http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/extending_latex.html) along the lines of:

```
\let\Oldtodo\todo
\renewcommand{\todo}[1]{\Oldtodo[inline]{#1}}
```

for this situation. I believe that `\let` is a plain TeX feature.