# Reference in Latex chapter style

Tags: latex

I would like to add a note in the Latex Chapter environment that the work
I am describing in the following has been published in a paper. In other words,
it should look something like this:

```
Chapter 6

The Evolution in research

The research described in this Chapter has been published in:
R. Moor and J.Morris. The Evolution of Research, Workshop on
Education, 2010, pp. 180-190


Once upon a time ....
```

Or alternatively:

```
The research described in this Chapter has been published in:
R. Moor and J.Morris. The Evolution of Research, Workshop on
Education, 2010, pp. 180-190

Chapter 6

The Evolution in research


Once upon a time ....
```

Anyone an idea if there is something like a template for doing that in Latex?

Many thanks,
Rob

Comment: There is a special stackexchange site for LaTaX Maybe asking this question there could get more results. http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Cheers Jens, I will have a look there!

Answer (score 1):

You could redefine the `\chapter` command to make it accept one more (optional) argument containing your description.

In order to use the same name, look at [Redefining latex macro using same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245247/redefining-latex-macro-using-same-name)