# Pandoc MD to PDF , full size horizontal rule

Tags: pdf, markdown, pandoc

I'm using pandoc (on windows with miktex)

with markdown i create a horizontal rule, save that as my source.md

```
---
```

(or even an hr tag instead)

but when I convert to PDF the horizontal rule is a tiny little line in the middle of the page, centered.

How do I get it to create one from margin to margin like it does when I convert it to HTML?

Edit:

I tried a CSS styled DIV tag that creates a rule but it is completely ignored during a pdf output.

Answer (score 8):

As pointed above, you can redefine the `\rule` command in your custom LaTeX template to ignore the first argument:

```
\let\OldRule\rule
\renewcommand{\rule}[2]{\OldRule{\linewidth}{#2}}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try `$\hrulefill$`. This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

The horizontal rule produces the LaTeX code `\begin{center}\rule{3in}{0.4pt}\end{center}` when using `pandoc -t latex`. So you might try to [redefine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245247/redefining-latex-macro-using-same-name) the `\rule` command in your custom [Pandoc template](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#templates).

Other than that, using ConTeXt instead of LaTeX already results in a full-size horizontal rule.

Comment: I only get "cannot produce pdf output with context writer", and google has no fix for that, trying to redefine rule though.